# How can I only use one dictionary and be able to output a third value related to the key pair?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been set a task by my lecturer to complete a couple challenges to help improve my understanding of dictionaries and the concepts behind them. I've been able to complete the first task quite easily but I'm quite stuck with the second task. The first task was to create a 'Who's your Daddy? program'.

The challenge states: Write a Who's Your Daddy program that lets the user enter the name of a male and produces the name of his father. (You can use celebrities, fictional characters, or even historical figures for fun.) Allow the user to add, replace, and delete son-father pairs.

I was able to create this challenge with only one issue where I could only replace a father of a son and not both.

The second challenge states: Improve this program by adding a choice that lets the user enter a name and get back a grandfather. Your program should still only use one dictionary of son-father pairs. Make sure to include several generations in you dictionary so that a match can be found.

I thought that I could maybe use a dictionary nested in a dictionary and researched that, but it only stated one dictionary. I then thought could I use a tuple within a dictionary and then access this tuple when the user requests a son and their grandfather, but have not had much luck with this either, so I decided to come on here.

So now I wonder, how can I add grandfathers to each of the pairs, can you add a second value to a key in a dictionary?

```
names = { "henry" : "michael",
          "louis" : "jason",
          "owen"  : "justin",
          "jake" : "glynn",
          "adam" : "mark",
          }

choice = None

while choice != "0":

    print(
        """
        Welcome to the Who's Your Daddy? program.
        You can find out a father of the names listed,
        you can then add, replace and delete a son/father pair.
        0 - Exit
        1 - List sons and their fathers
        2 - Add a pair
        3 - Replace a pair
        4 - Delete a pair
        """
        )

    choice = input("Choice: ")

    #exit
    if choice == "0":
        print("Goodbye")

    #List sons
    if choice == "1":
        print(*names.keys(), sep='\n')   
        son_choice = input("Who's father would you like to know the name of?: ")
        if son_choice in names:
            print(names[son_choice])
        else:
            print("That name is not in the list!")

    #Add a pair
    elif choice == "2":
        son_add = input("Enter the name of someone: ").lower()
        if son_add not in names:
            father_add = input("Now enter the name of their father: ").lower()
            names[son_add] = father_add
            print("That pair has been added")
        else:
            print("That name already exists!")


    #Replace a pair
    elif choice == "3":
        son_replace = input("What name do you want to replace?: ")
        if son_replace in names:
            father_replace = input("Enter the name of their father: ")
            names[son_replace] = father_replace
            print("The pair has been replaced")
        else:
            print("That name doesn't exist, please add it first!")

    #Delete a pair
    elif choice == "4":
        son_delete = input("What name do you want me to delete?: ")
        if son_delete in names:
            del names[son_delete]
            print("Pair deleted!")
        else:
            print("That pair does not exist!")

    else:
        print("Sorry, that's an invalid choice!")

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit!")
```

Comment: If keys are sons and values are fathers, first find the father, then look through the keys again for that father's name (value).

Comment: A grandfather is just the father of the father.

Comment: Ok, I sort of understand what you mean, I know the grandfather is just a father of the father, I don't see how going through the keys again will find their grandfather, how would I implement this?

Comment: Given a son `son_choice`, `names[son_choice]` would be the son's father, right? So who is the father of `names[son_choice]`?

Comment: Ok I understand this, but how would I create a father to the names[son_choice], who would then be the grandfather to the son?

Comment: I've had a play around and finally completed it I believe, to actually search for a grandfather in the first place, I need to create a pair for instance, tom, who's father is henry, so when I then go to find a grandfather, the result should be michael

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Ronald and a little common sense I've now solve this issue.

For a grandfather to be found, I needed to create a new son father pair where the son's father would be a son already in the list. For example, if I create a new pair, with the son being called tom and the father being called henry. I can then use the find the grandfather function to show that tom's grandfather would be michael.

```
   #Find a grandfather
    elif choice == "5":
        grandson = input("Please enter the son and I will find the grandfather: ").lower()

        if grandson in names:
            father = names[grandson]
            if father in names:
                grandfather = names[father]
                print("The grandfather of " + grandson + " is " + grandfather)
            else:
                print(father + " is not in the dictionary")

        else:
            print(grandson + " is not in the dictionary")
```

This is the code I created, however, how would I make this work for several generations, or is that already accomplished by this piece of code.

Comment: I've also updated the dictionary to have older and younger generations based on the original sons, which I believe answers my own question.